# Конструктор класса с++, принимающий на вход многомерный initalizer_list

Tags: c++, qtcreator, g++, шаблоны-с++

Задался задачей по написанию шаблонного контейнера, который в памяти хранится как одномерный. При этом со всей необходимой математикой и прочими преобразованиями. Для начала хотелось написать конструктор, который принимал бы на вход многомерный initalizer_list (brace-enclosed initializer_list).

Начал реализацию с этого:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <initializer_list>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class array{
private:

    T* data;
    int* shape;

public:

    array(){
        this->data = new T[1]{1};
        this->shape = new int[1]{1};
    }

    template <typename B>
    array(initializer_list <B> input_data){

        const char* TypeName = typeid(input_data).name(); //
        const char* iter = TypeName;                      //
        iter += strlen(TypeName) - 1;                     //
                                                          // Костыльно определяем размерность
        int dimensionality = 0;                           //
        while (*iter-- == 'E'){                           //
            dimensionality++;                             //
        }                                                 //

        this->shape = new int [dimensionality];
        this->shape[0] = input_data.size();               // Костыльно    заполняем shape

        int input_size = input_data.size();

        this->data = new T [input_data.size()];                                 //
                                                                                //
        const B* item = input_data.begin();                                     //
                                                                                //
        for (int index_data = 0 ; index_data < input_size ; index_data++){      // Костыльно заполняем data
            this->data[index_data] = *item++;                                   //
        }                                                                       //

    }

    int size(){
        return this->shape[0];
    }

};

#endif // ARRAY_H
```

При этом интересующий конструктор работает на одномерных объектах, но, при выполнении следующего кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "array.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    array <int> first_test_array;

    cout << "Тест конструктора без аргументов :\n" << first_test_array.size() << endl;

    array <int> second_test_array {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    cout << "Тест конструктора с одномерным initializer_list :\n" << second_test_array.size() << endl << endl;

    array <int> third_test_array {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 5}, {6, 7}}}; // Падает здесь

    cout << "Тест конструктора с многомерным initializer_list :\n" << third_test_array.size() << endl;

}
```

Пишет вот такую ошибку:

```
In funstion 'int main()':
/home/artyom/CPP/array/main.cpp:16: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'array<int>::array(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
 array <int> third_test_array {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 5}, {6, 7}}};
                                                                 ^
/home/artyom/CPP/array/main.cpp:16: candidates are:
/home/artyom/CPP/array/main.cpp:2: In file included from ../array/main.cpp:2:0:
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:25: template<class B> array<T>::array(std::initializer_list<B>)
 array(initializer_list <B> input_data){
 ^

/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/artyom/CPP/array/main.cpp:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
 array <int> third_test_array {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 5}, {6, 7}}};
                                                                 ^
/home/artyom/CPP/array/main.cpp:2: In file included from ../array/main.cpp:2:0:
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:19: array<T>::array() [with T = int]
 array(){
 ^
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:11: constexpr array<int>::array(const array<int>&)
class array{
   ^
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:11: constexpr array<int>::array(array<int>&&)
/home/artyom/CPP/array/array.h:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provide
```

Может ли мне кто-либо объяснить как это сделать?

Comment: Дополнительно: избавьтесь от `using namespace` в заголовочном файле. Это зло. И лучше не называть свой класс `array` при наличии `using namespace std;` в файле реализации, т.к. такое имя уже есть в стандартной библиотеке и, достаточно `#include <array>` чтобы появились ещё новые ошибки компиляции.

Comment: Спасибо, я учту это в дальнейшем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам поможет: http://christophercrouzet.com/blog/post/2015/01/12/Nested-Initializer-Lists-for-Multidimensional-Arrays

Код можно посмотреть тут: https://github.com/christophercrouzet/m3ta/blob/master/src/m3ta/. Например, реализация вложенного initializer_list: https://github.com/christophercrouzet/m3ta/blob/master/src/m3ta/nestedinitializerlists.h

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что в некоторых ситуациях типы не могут быть выведены для шаблонов. И наличие неявного `std::initializer_list` в передаваемых аргументах одна из таких ситуаций. Выдержка из Стандрарта [14.8.2.5/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   ... 
>   A function parameter for which the
>   associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the
>   parameter does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer
>   list is specified ([temp.deduct.call]). [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T); 
> g({1,2,3});                 // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Чтобы Ваш код работал нужно добавить конструктор, принимающий например список списков `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<B>>` или например список пар `std::initializer_list<std::pair<B,B>>`, если планируется использовать только пары во вложенных списках.

Можно ещё явно преобразовать типы при вызове, но это, конечно, не удобно использовать:

`{std::initializer_list<int>{0, 1}, std::initializer_list<int>{2, 3}}`

Comment: Спасибо, но мне хотелось бы передать туда именно многомерный объект, при этом число измерений неизвестно заранее. Как я понимаю по средством шаблонов это невозможно. В тоже время и писать "руками" конструктор для 100-мерного объекта - вовсе не решение. Возможно рекурсивно?

Answer (score 0):

У вас конструктор `array(initializer_list <B> input_data)`, следовательно ожидается массив объектов B. Вы же пытаетесь инициализировать его с помощью массива массивов объектов B. Думаю, что вам приедятся определить конструктор`array(initializer_list<initializer_list <B>>  input_data)`

Comment: Спасибо. Приведён только пример. В обзем случаи там будут многомерные объекты, например 6-ти мерные.